# WPF TextBlock font looks ok when selected in Visual Studio, but not ok when out of focus

Tags: wpf, fonts, rendering

In visual studio I am using Proxima Nova Regular (size 13px) inside a TextBox. However when I focus out of the TextBox in VS the font suddenly becomes smaller/flatter.

Any ideas?

In focus where text shows corrently:http://cl.ly/image/2O04370h063H

Font renders strange when out of focus and looks more like 12px: http://cl.ly/image/1g0t1S1r1447

Comment: Are you getting this problem only in the VS designer or is the problem occurring when you run the app as well?

Comment: It's happening when running the app as well. It seems like Windows renders the font OK, it's when it's in the WPF it renders differently. I know it's never been great with WPF but there were improvements since v4.

Comment: I've also tried setting different combinations of TextFormattingMode and TextRenderingMode (ie. Display + ClearType, Ideal + Aliased)

Comment: Okay, so I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Here are some ideas: Set `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` and/or `UseLayoutRounding="True"`. Use a different (standard Windows) font, such as `Segoe UI`. Adjust the font size by 0.5 px (e.g., use `13.5px` or `12.5px`).

Comment: Thanks Ming - I'll try those things. 13.5 makes it closer to what it should look like. When you say you can't reproduce the problem, are you trying it with Proxima Nova?

Comment: No, I don't have Proxima Nova -- which is why I suggested that you try using a different font.